# Repairing a partially cut roof strut

Tags: framing, attic, structural

It looks like some previous owner of my house (built in the 40s) cut almost the whole way through a roof strut (I think it's called a strut) when installing an attic ladder in the garage.  I am wondering if I can sister something to the roof framing or if I'm looking at a more involved repair.

Here is a diagram of the roof framing in the attic:

[image: Sketch of roof framing]

Here is a photo of the cut.  It's horizontal and goes about 2/3rds of the way through the strut:

[image: Photo of the cut]

[image: Wide shot showing entire attic]

Comment: Can you get us a picture of an unmodified location for comparison.

Comment: @FreeMan alas, no.  There is only one of these!  It's in the middle of the attic above the garage - the roof above the main house just has rafters and collar ties.  I'll add a zoomed out image in case it gives more context though

Answer (score 15):

You could put two plywood plates either side to strengthen it.

But you may not need to. How long has it been like that? Is the snow load significant?

Just remember that that strut is working in compression not tension.

Comment: The snow load is non-existent.  This is a SF bay area home, so maybe earthquakes are more of a concern.

I've only owned this house for a year - the PO had it for around 10 I think - I suspect this was done even earlier but it's difficult to know.

Comment: Given the very light engineering of the truss and roof members, there is unlikely to be any significant snow load.  A roof like that even in perfect condition would collapse anywhere significant snowfall would be expected.  Looks like a 10psf or maybe 20psf design at most.  Loading on the attic floor would be more concerning here.

Comment: Hardware store steel tie plates would be a bit more compact than plywood, possibly cheaper depending on whether or not Pete has already got spare plywood laying around.

Answer (score 8):

It's not likely a problem. Many such roofs don't have that center bracing to begin with. There's no beam above (just a light ridge board), so it's fairly minor bracing.

If it worries you, lay a rail of 3/4" plywood or two-by lumber horizontally behind the three members and screw it all together with any screws you have laying around. It'll be stronger than it was originally with those puny 6d nails.

Comment: Be careful using sheetrock screws, they have a very low sheer point.

Comment: [Not much worse than other screws](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3mBvRs5Rmk) based on this testing, @boatcoder.

Comment: @FreeMan [This](https://www.popularwoodworking.com/article/screws-screws-arent/) test from _Popular Woodworking_ indicates that heat treatment may be important.

Comment: @wumpusD'00m this is essentially the same testing done in the video I linked (based on a link originally posted by isherwood on another question). He had the same results with the cheapie "wood screws", and attributed some of the other differences to advanced thread shapes, point geometry & under head fluting.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to put a nail plate/tie plate over the board on both sides to restore the original strength.  It's not clear if this would fit based upon the photos.

[image: Nail Plate/Tie Plate]

Alternately a gusset plate which would be a triangle of 1/2 structural ply going across all three members (say 12" tall) on both sides and nailed with a tight pattern should bring it back to the original structural strength.  The screws that appear to be in there are likely not structural as structural screws have been showing up within the last 10 years or so.  Non-structural wood screws typically don't have well defined shear strength which is why humble nails are often specified.

[image: Plywood Gusset Plate]

Answer (score 1):

That member looks like it would be in compression, which leaves you better-off than if it was in tension.

Look at the far side and see if the cut is square (cut is visible), or has a triangular profile(cut hasn't gone through).  If the cut was done with a circular saw the bottom is probably curved but close-enough to triangular.

As a test, try pushing a thin knife blade or similar into the slot - It may bottom out quickly in which case there's plenty of wood in there.  Feel for nails through the slot - if you can go all the way through and there are no nails, then the slot hasn't squashed up on itself and the load is small.

As a sop to one's inner voice, you could cut some hardwood into a thin slice, and put a wedge shape on one end, then tap it into place using wood glue as a lubricant.  Flush-cut the exposed pieces and let it dry.
You might choose to hammer a nail plate over the joint, more to disguise it than for any practical purpose.